# Entering the US with a round trip ticket

Tags: visas

I just received my K1-visa and everyhting is perfectly fine. The whole process went very smooth. But now i need to buy a ticket to the US. Officially this would be a one way ticket because i will not go back to Europe again - ofcourse not since i will be marrying my finace. But a roundtrip is way cheaper than a one way ticket. Would the immigration officer consider me having a round trip ticket being a potential malafide person? He might think i plan to return soon

Answer (score 4):

The immigration officer will have no problem with your round trip ticket. Most people know it is cheaper to buy a round trip ticket.

Additionally you are allowed to return to your country after getting married (or not) and notifying USCIS. It does not imply a bad faith marriage

Comment: "Additionally you are allowed to return to your country after getting married (or not) and notifying USCIS." It's not as simple as "notifying USCIS". They need to have gotten Advance Parole to leave the US without abandoning a pending Adjustment of Status. First, after marriage, they have to apply for Adjustment of Status. They can apply for Advance Parole at the same time as, or after applying for Adjustment of Status. Advance Parole takes up to 6 months these days to get.